How to pass value of type ‘Set’ to custom hibernate 6.4 sql function
I am trying to create a containsAll custom SQL-function for PostgreSQL but I have difficulties with passing the value to the SQL.
The part of the output in the SQL is:
(kba1_0.labels @> bytea '\xaced0005737200116a6176612e7574696c2e48617368536574ba44859596b8b7340300007870770c000000103f400000000000017400066c6162656c3178')

So argument(0) seems to be fine and the issue is about how argument(1) is treated. It converts the set into this binary which I don't want.
My code looks like the following:
public class ContainsAll extends StandardSQLFunction {
    public static final String NAME = "__containsAll";

    public ContainsAll() {
        super(NAME, false, StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN);
    }

  @Override
      public void render(
          SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> arguments, ReturnableType<?> returnType,
          SqlAstTranslator<?> translator
      ) {
          sqlAppender.append('(');
          arguments.get(0).accept(translator);
          sqlAppender.append(" @> ");
          arguments.get(1).accept(translator); // How to do this correctly here?
          sqlAppender.append(")");
      }
}

Here is how i call the function (value is the 'Set") please don't wonder about the weird method signature:
public static <T extends BaseEntity, A extends Serializable> Specification<T> containsAll2(
        SingularAttribute<? super T, ? extends Collection> attribute, Collection<A> value
    ) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            return builder.isTrue(builder.function(ContainsAll.NAME,
                Boolean.class,
                root.get(attribute),
                builder.literal(value) // Or is this a problem?
            ));
        };
    }

